# How to get one class using interface?

Tags: c#, class, interface

I've searched Google, I could only find how to get ALL classes using an interface. I want to know if an object inherits an interface?

For some further explanation, I have several classes that use `IEquipable`. I'm trying to check if an `IEquipable` is a `Firearm`.

I've tried

```
(Firearm)currentItem.damage
```

but that does not work. currentItem is a IEquipable.

Comment: With the current information in the question, it's impossible for anybody to be able to help you. What is `IEquipable`? What type does `currentItem.damage` return? Are you trying to store the value of `currentItem.damage` or do you want to know the type?

Comment: Well you are accessing the damage property before cast takes places... So you need another parenthesis ((Firearm)currentItem).damage.. If you want to check class, you can use is or cast it with as and check if the result is not null...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (currentItem is Firearm)
{
    var firearm = (Firearm)currentItem;
    var damage = firearm.damage;
}
```

or

```
var firearm = currentItem as Firearm;
if (firearm != null) 
{
    var damage = firearm.damage;
}
```

Comment: I used the first and it works perfectly. Edit: the second one works as well.